# Is it a good practice to use a vector of bytes as raw storage for other types?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, entity-component-system

I've started to follow an ECS tutorial on YouTube and I've never seen anyone allocating a new variable into a `vector` of `uint8` before.

```
template<typename Component>
uint32 ECSComponentCreate(Array<uint8>& memory, EntityHandle entity, BaseECSComponent* comp)
{
    uint32 index = memory.size();
    memory.resize(index+Component::SIZE);
    Component* component = new(&memory[index])Component(*(Component*)comp);
    component->entity = entity;
    return index;
}
```

(the full code in question can be found [here](https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameProgrammingTutorial/blob/49364a13a55bc5b606e125e6cb4bff1faf258efe/src/ecs/ecsComponent.hpp#L57); `Array` here is [`#define Array std::vector`](https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameProgrammingTutorial/blob/49364a13a55bc5b606e125e6cb4bff1faf258efe/src/dataStructures/array.hpp#L5))

How does it differ from using a vector of pointers, why is it better?

Comment: That particular implementation of pool allocator seems to disregard completely alignment constraints, which is not good for performance on x86 and leads to crashes on less forgiving platforms (as far as the standard is concerned it's undefined behavior).

Comment: By the way, you should really include the relevant code in your questions to make them self-contained, github repos come and go...

Comment: The pool allocator is new to me but it looks interesting. I have started to learn more about it just as @john-zwinck pointed out this allocation strategy.
And thank you for the Github suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically a "pool allocator."  Now that you know what it's called you can read about why it's done, but performance is generally the motivation.

All the allocations are done in a single vector, and at the end the whole vector can be deallocated at once (after destroying the objects within, which you can see in the deallocation function just below).

Answer (score 0):

The two gotchas to me with using a `vector` of bytes are:

1. Alignment. Though you can solve that with an aligned allocator. If you aren't aware of what types are being stored in advance and their alignment requirements until runtime, a slightly wasteful (but not so much for a handful of hefty containers) is just use a maximum alignment for the dynamic allocations.
2. This is the bigger gotcha in my book, and that has to do with how vector reallocates its array when you insert elements to it. If you're storing non-trivially constructive/destructible types in there, that could potentially wreck havoc by copying their bytes around in memory without properly invoking the necessary move/copy ctors and dtors.

If you want to make your ECS store brand new component types contiguously in memory then a much less dangerous approach I recommend is abstract your component container, like so:

```
struct Components
{
     virtual ~Components() {}
};

template <class T>
struct ComponentsT: public Components
{
     std::vector<T> components;
};
```

When you want to register a new component type, `Foo`, to the system, you can dynamically allocate and instantiate `ComponentsT<Foo>`, stick that in a polymorphic container (a container of containers), and when you want to add a `Foo` component to an entity (and therefore instantiate it and add it to the components list), grab the relevant abstract `Components*` base pointer/ref, downcast it (can use `dynamic_cast`) to `ComponentsT<Foo>*`, then push back your component instance there. Now you got all your `Foos` stored contiguously in memory without dealing with alignment and invalidation and so forth.